# innerHTML isn't working with getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, firefox, innerhtml

I'm just a beginner. And I'm trying to use `innerHTML`.
I think I wrote proper code, but it doesn't work.
When I click the trigger, the page becomes white and showing the statut : 'connecting'
I don't know where is the problem

Please someone help me.

Here are my codes.

HTML CODE

```
<div class = "head">
<nav>
<a onClick="open()">

<div class = "body">
<div class = "bodyL">
<div class = "newsPnT">
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
function open() {
   document.getElementsByClassName('newsPnT').innerHTML = "asdfasdfasdf";
}
```

What is the problem with my code?

PS: I'm using Firefox Aurora. When I click the trigger, the 'debugger > sources' says, 'waiting for sources.'

Comment: In addition to the answer given bellow (`getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object), please note that the `innerHTML` causes a lot of issues (security, DOM reflow). You can use `textContent` for the above example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

getElementsByClassName() returns array with elements.

> Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names. When called on the document object, the complete document is searched, including the root node. You may also call getElementsByClassName() on any element; it will return only elements which are descendants of the specified root element with the given class names.

So you need iterate array and set innerHTML like this i.e.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
    element.innerHTML = 'Your text goes here';
});
```

Also a little bonus [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FadXW/)

Answer (score 0):

the className 'open' seemed to the keyword of javascript. 
I changed the className from 'open' to 'openThis'and that came to be a solution of the problem.