# Why isn't getElementsByClassName working?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I can't understand why getElementsByClassName isn't working here.

```js
  n = new Date();
  y = n.getFullYear();
  document.getElementByClassName("date").innerHTML = y;
```

```html
<span class="date"></span> CompanyName
```

Comment: It returns a **list** of elements, and you have to iterate through it and act on each element individually. Also it's spelled as it is in your question title, not your posted code, which would have resulted in an exception in your browser console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [innerHTML isn't working with getElementsByClassName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936658/innerhtml-isnt-working-with-getelementsbyclassname)

Comment: This: **`document.getElementByClassName`** is a typo in addition to the other comments.

Comment: You are getting a Array back with ByClassName. so you could do this if your only expecting 1 back. document.getElementByClassName("date")[0].innerHTML

Comment: I forgot the array. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The function name is `getElementsByClassName`, not `getElementByClassName`
2. `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object of elements, not the one of elements.

Code should look like this:

```js
n = new Date();
y = n.getFullYear();
document.getElementsByClassName("date")[0].innerHTML = y;
```

```html
<span class="date"></span> CompanyName
```

Comment: One note: it doesn’t return an array but rather a collection of nodes which is iterable but does not inherit array prototype methods like map or forEach.