# How to increment a variable by 1 for every 100 in another variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I am trying to create a function that once the button is pressed, it takes the input in a variable, let's say n, and checks if the number is divisible by 100. If it is, it needs to increment a second variable, lets say m, by 1 for every 100.
Hopefully this makes sense!

So far I've tried this:

```
function Convert()  {
        var cp = document.getElementsByClassName("copper").value;
        var sp = document.getElementsByClassName("silver").value;
        var ep = document.getElementsByClassName("electrum").value;
        var gp = document.getElementsByClassName("gold").value;

        if (cp % 100 === 0)  {
            gp++;
        }

        if (sp % 10 === 0)  {
            gp++;
        }

        if (ep % 2 === 0)   {
            gp++;
        }

        document.getElementsByClassName("result").innerHTML = "gp";
}
```

It get's the values from this code:

```
return  (
    <Container>

    <><Row>
            <Col>
                <Card className="copp">
                    <Card.Header>Copper</Card.Header>
                    <Card.Body>100cp = 1gp</Card.Body>
                    <input type="number" className="copper"></input>
                </Card>
            </Col>

            <Col>
                <Card className="silv">
                    <Card.Header>Silver</Card.Header>
                    <Card.Body>10sp = 1gp</Card.Body>
                    <input type="number" className="silver"></input>
                </Card>
            </Col>

            <Col>
                <Card className="elec">
                    <Card.Header>Electrum</Card.Header>
                    <Card.Body>2ep = 1gp</Card.Body>
                    <input type="number" className="electrum"></input>
                </Card>
            </Col>
        </Row>
        
        <Row>
            <Col>
                <Card className="golden">
                    <Card.Header>Gold</Card.Header>
                    <Card.Body>1gp</Card.Body>
                    <input type="number" className="gold"></input>
                </Card>
            </Col>

            <Col>
                <Card className="logo d-none">
                    <Card.Img />
                </Card>
            </Col>
        
            <Col>
                <Card className="plat">
                    <Card.Header>Platinum</Card.Header>
                    <Card.Body>1pp = 10gp</Card.Body>
                    <input type="number" className="platinum"></input>
                </Card>
            </Col>
        </Row>

        <Row>
            <div className="text-center">
                <Button variant="primary" type="submit" className="w-25" onClick={Convert()}>
                    Submit
                </Button>
            </div>
        </Row></>
        
   

    <Card className="mx-auto">
        <Card.Header>Results</Card.Header>
        <Card.Body className="result"></Card.Body>
    </Card>

    </Container>

)
```

I've checked some of it in the MDN code editor, and it works to an extent. It won't keep increasing the variable by 1 when I run it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't getElementsByClassName working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56534225/why-isnt-getelementsbyclassname-working)

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want to write `gp = gp + ep/2 + sp/10 + cp/100;`?

Comment: You should rather do something like `gp += Math.floor(cp / 100); cp %= 100`

Comment: So the getElementsByClassName I've now sorted, thanks for that!
However, for the Math.floor(), how could I then use this to check the other currencies, and add them to the gp variable? For example, the sp needs to be for every 10, increase gp by 1. And for ep needs to be for every 2, increase gp by 1.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve this by doing the following:

> I change from React to vanilla JS, HTML and CSS.
> I have used the following JS function to work out what I needed:

```
// Function which obtains each value from the cards and works out how much
// of each currency is left.

function convert()  {
    
    let c = document.getElementById("copper").value;
    let s = document.getElementById("silver").value;
    let e = document.getElementById("electrum").value;
    let g = document.getElementById("gold").value;
    let p = document.getElementById("platinum").value;

    let cpnumber = Math.floor(c / 100);
    let spnumber = Math.floor(s / 10);
    let epnumber = Math.floor(e / 2);
    let gpnumber = Math.floor(g / 1);

    let cpremainder = Math.floor(c % 100);
    let spremainder = Math.floor(s % 10);
    let epremainder = Math.floor(e % 2);

    const goldOutcome = cpnumber + spnumber + epnumber + gpnumber;

    document.getElementById("goldNumber").innerHTML = goldOutcome;
    document.getElementById("silverNumber").innerHTML = spremainder;
    document.getElementById("copperNumber").innerHTML = cpremainder;
    // console.log(cpnumber);
    // console.log(gpnumber);
    // console.log(cpremainder);
    // console.log(spremainder);
    // console.log(epremainder);
}


// Function to reset all inputs and results back to zero
function clearAll() {

    // Resetting each input back to zero
    document.getElementById("copper").value = "";
    document.getElementById("silver").value = "";
    document.getElementById("electrum").value = "";
    document.getElementById("gold").value = "";
    document.getElementById("platinum").value = "";

    // Resetting results back to zero
    document.getElementById("goldNumber").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("silverNumber").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("copperNumber").innerHTML = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The getElementsByClassName method of Document interface returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given className(s).if you write document.getElementsByClassName then it will return an array of HTML elements even if every elements are given unique className.like
var cp = document.getElementsByClassName("copper").value;
this will return an HTML array like

```
HTMLCollection(1)
>>["Card"]
[[Prototype]]
HTMLCollection
```

then you have to access them giving index like:
var cp = document.getElementsByClassName("copper")[0].value;
so make sure if you have different attributes then instead of using classname use id.at the end className is plural so it returns an array of HTML elements and id is singular so it returns the direct value of a HTML element.
You can use this in your code :

```
 <Col>
        <Card className="copp"> //make classname to id
            <Card.Header>Copper</Card.Header>
            <Card.Body>100cp = 1gp</Card.Body>
            <input type="number" className="copper"></input>
        </Card>
    </Col>

    <Col>
        <Card className="silv">//make classname to id
            <Card.Header>Silver</Card.Header>
            <Card.Body>10sp = 1gp</Card.Body>
            <input type="number" className="silver"></input>
        </Card>
    </Col>

    <Col>
        <Card className="elec">//make classname to id
            <Card.Header>Electrum</Card.Header>
            <Card.Body>2ep = 1gp</Card.Body>
            <input type="number" className="electrum"></input>
        </Card>
    </Col>
var cp = document.getElementById("copper").value;
var sp = document.getElementById("silver").value;
var ep = document.getElementById("electrum").value;
var gp = document.getElementById("gold").value;
```